# ColdFusion 10 Web Service Timeout Issue

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

I have an issue with a ColdFusion 10 Web Service on an internal network. I continually receive a timeout when attempting to consume a remote web service. I researched many similar issues on the internet but they are so varied, from network settings to the ColdFusion connector needing to be reinstalled etc. that I am not sure where to start as it may effect other applications on the same server. I already have timeout attributes in place.

When attempting to access the full wsdl URL in the browser address bar it renders with no issues on the same server I am attempting to initiate the web service.

I am consuming and publishing under wsVersion 1.

Could anyone please provide assistance in troubleshooting this issue. I have provided the following details to help troubleshoot.

Error from Attempting Web Service.

```
AxisFault
faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
faultSubcode:
faultString: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
faultActor:
faultNode:
faultDetail:
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.Def... ''

Web Service Log from attempting to run web service this morning. Removed http prefix

Jul 22, 2014       8:23 AM       Information       ajp-bio-8012-exec-8        
Web service request completed {Time taken=21048 ms}
Jul 22, 2014       8:23 AM       Information       ajp-bio-8012-exec-8        
Starting Web service request.
Jul 22, 2014       8:23 AM       Information       ajp-bio-8012-exec-8        
Creating Web service proxy {url='//internal-site.com/services/customer360/FluService.cfc?wsdl'}
Jul 22, 2014       8:23 AM       Information       ajp-bio-8012-exec-8        
Using Axis 1 for consuming the service //internal-site.com/services/customer360/FluService.cfc.

ColdFusion Server Information

Server Product     ColdFusion
Version     10,0,13,287689
Tomcat Version     7.0.23.0
Edition     Enterprise 
Serial Number     xxxx-5644 
Operating System     Windows Server 2008 R2 
OS Version     6.1 
Update Level     /D:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/updates/chf10000013.jar 
Adobe Driver Version     4.1 (Build 0001)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried testing the webservice through a tool like soap-ui? This could help determine which end the issue is at.

Comment: Are you able to expose the url in the browser?

Comment: @Alan - installing now - will let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Anit - yes the fully qualified wsdl renders immediately in the browser...

Comment: If you copy the function to a .cfm page, how long does it take to run it?

Comment: Does the wsdl render immediately in the browser _from the ColdFusion server_? Just want to make sure you test from the ColdFusion server itself and not your own workstation. (Assuming they are different.) It might also help to see the code you are using to consume the web service.

Comment: It turns out I needed to add proxy attributes to the invocation. I was not aware the server required that. Thanks to all for your support.

Comment: Example: <cfinvoke 
  webservice="#wsURL#"
  method="getReservation"
 returnvariable="result"
 refreshwsdl="no"
 timeout="120"
 wsversion="1"
 proxyPassword = "pw" 
 proxyPort = "80" 
 proxyServer = "IPADDRESS">
    <cfinvokeargument name="customerNum" value="#arguments.customerNum#"/>
 <cfinvokeargument name="reservationID" value="#reReplace(order_num,"^0+","")#"/>
 <cfinvokeargument name="withDetail" value="false"/>
 <cfinvokeargument name="onlyOpenLines" value="true"/>
</cfinvoke>

Comment: @JasonLuciano go ahead and add your solution as an answer to your own question.  It is okay to do that here and that will be easier for people to find than buried in these comments. Glad you figured it out.